# QGIS Automation of Nested reports

Tags: qgis-3, reports

QGIS 3.22.4 with shapefiles

Scenario: Streets(shapefile line). Each Street can have several stakes (shapefile points), each stakes can have several pannels (shapefile line).

For each shapefile, I have a one page report, and as the reference of the streetid is available in attributes of every shapefiles, getting the reports means executing the 3 reports individually with the streetid as filter.

As I want to present the final report as street report, and for each stake report add the related pannels report. A manual sorting is needed.

I would like to automate further and have some kind of makro report, receiving the street id and automatically give the the street report, the stake reports, but for each stake, just after its report, the related pannels reports.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you read this : https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/report/ ? If not it could probably help

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks

Comment: I had a quick look, and it seems promising. Is there a way to take advantage of reports that has already been done by the standard individua way, ie copy them to this system, even if I have to make some modifications?

Comment: And Atlas functionalities can be used?

Comment: And I just want to have the reports for the streets that have been fully analysed ( an attribute in the street table), so I had to put a filter : where?

Comment: I did some tests with this feature, but the result is wrong.

Comment: The link between the first level and the second level is not applied. The fields are identical and I followed strictly the procedure refrerenced. The seceond level presents ALL the data and not just the ones with the similar field!

Comment: Any reaction to this question?

Comment: As suggested, I re-wrote my request : I want to do a 3 level report, first level the roads, second level the stakes along each road, and 3rd level the pannels on each stake. So if I have 2 roads (road1 and road 2), the first road with 1 stake (stake 1) with 3 pannels (pan 1,2,3), the second road with 2 stakes (stake 2 , 3), the first (stake 2) with 2 pannels (pan 4-5) and the 2nd (stake 3) with 1 pannel (pan 5) So what I would like to have is an automatic report that will print the following reports : road 1 / stake1 / Pan 1/ pan 2 / pan 3 / road 2 / stake 2 / pan 4 / pan 5 / stake 3 /pan 5

Comment: This will greatly help me because the real project has about 100 roads, 250 stakes, 600 pannels... WIth the simple test I did, it appears that the link between road, stake and pan did not work, so I had (with the exemple given) road1 / stake 1 / all the pans / stake 2 /all the pans again / stake 3 / all the pans/stake 4 /all the pans ...... and then again the same with road 2. even after reading the tips on that report feature.